# Flutter local package navigate to root module

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-packages

I have a flutter local package, called "profile" and i have included and using this package from my main application as below

on pubspec.yaml file under dependencies i added the below code.

```
profile:
    path: ./profile
```

Everything working well and good.

My issue is I want to navigate to MaterialApp -> Route when use click on a button in "Profile" package.

I tried to use Global navigation key

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

and from profile package when i use below code on button press

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/', arguments: null);
```

It's doing nothing. Could you please help me with this.

Many thanks in advance.